# eclipse does not recognize android constants

Tags: android, visibility

I know this may be a simple question but eclipse does not recognize android constants like VISIBLE :

```
ImageView bin = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.delete_icon);
bin.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

is there a reason for that ?

Comment: Because it's actually `View.VISIBLE`

Comment: It was not specified in Google doc...

Comment: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
bin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

It needs to know what class that constant belongs to